# Is there any place where I can find .blend files of car interior parts

Tags: blend-files

I want to know website where I can find 3D .blend interior car parts like steering wheels etc.
Please answer as soon as possible. I need this urgently for my fyp project.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/599

Comment: The [OpelGT by Rogper](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/57359) would be the most detailed car you will find, the engine would be the only thing not modelled.

Answer (score 1):

Blendswap.com contains lots of free Blender models. You can find there some car parts too. E.g. http://www.blendswap.com/blends/tagged/car

Comment: well I just checked there.. and they are only providing tires and rims.. I need internal parts like steering wheels and gear console..